# My action is never executed

Tags: ios, audio, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

```
var c = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("SelectMTN.wav", waitForCompletion: false

if touchedNode.name == "how" && howButton.hidden == false {
    //The action that is not running
    self.runAction(c)

    for node in self.children{
        node.removeFromParent()
    }

    var reloadScene : SKScene = howToPLay(size: self.size)
    self.view?.presentScene(reloadScene)
}
```

My sound is never played. I first thought it was because I had it at the end of the block but now it simply does not play.

Comment: Take a loot at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697478/skaction-playsoundfilenamed-from-singleton